# remove a specific sign with regex

Tags: php, regex

I wonder how to remove a "question mark char" from string like that:

```
8�901.9631
```

I'd like to use regex. I'm trying with this regex:

```
#(\d+).(\d+(?:\.\d{1,4})?)#
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know all other characters are numbers and periods, you could do this:

```
$string = '8�901.9631';
$new_string = preg_replace('/[^\d\.]/', '', $string);
echo $new_string; //8901.9631
```

Basically this is removing everything that is *not* (`[^  ]`) a number (`\d`) or a period (`\.`).

Comment: That begs the question of whether the `8901.9631` you get afterwards is acceptable. But otherwise, +1

Answer (score 3):

If you need to clean up a string and convert it to float you can use `filter_var` method for example:

```
filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
```